# Strange C# compiler behavior (overload resolution)

Tags: c#, .net, overload-resolution

I've found very strange C# compiler behavior for following code:

```
    var p1 = new SqlParameter("@p", Convert.ToInt32(1));
    var p2 = new SqlParameter("@p", 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(p1.Value, p2.Value); // PASS

    var x = 0;
    p1 = new SqlParameter("@p", Convert.ToInt32(x));
    p2 = new SqlParameter("@p", x);
    Assert.AreEqual(p1.Value, p2.Value); // PASS

    p1 = new SqlParameter("@p", Convert.ToInt32(0));
    p2 = new SqlParameter("@p", 0);
    Assert.AreEqual(p1.Value, p2.Value); // FAIL!?
```

In last line assert fails with following message:

```
  Expected: 0
  But was:  null
```

I understand why test fails: `p2 = new SqlParameter("@p", 0);` is resolved as `SqlParameter(string, SqlDbType)` and for other cases as `SqlParameter(string, object)`. But I don't understand why this happens. For me it looks like a bug, but I can't believe that C# compiler could have such kind of bug.

Any reasons for this?

P.S. It seems to be a problem for any method overload with enum parameter and 0 value (SqlDbType is enum).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, the decimal integer literal `0` is implicitly convertible to all enum types (C# 4 spec §6.1.3), so the compiler determines that `SqlParameter(string, SqlDbType)` is an applicable function member. Then it has to choose the better between two candidates function members, and it picks `SqlParameter(string, SqlDbType)` over `SqlParameter(string, object)`, because `SqlDbType` is a more specific type than `object` (§7.5.3.2).

But I agree that in that case it's very confusing...

Comment: Just an idea, what happens when setting the warning level to maximum? Maybe it will warn about that in this case.

Comment: @VictorHaydin, because the spec says so... "An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal 0 to be converted to any enum-type and to any nullable-type whose underlying type is an enum-type". Now, I don't know why it was designed this way, but there's probably a good reason... you need to ask someone from the C# team.